# Cocoa's Event Driven System: where do background tasks run?

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, nsrunloop, event-driven

On Mac OS X, Cocoa is event driven. By this I mean each thing is driven by the UI -  the user clicking something or moving over a certain area results in an event handler being called. Main simply calls NSApplicationMain () which creates an infinite loop till the program exits.

What about tasks that aren't user driven though? Where would I put tasks that need to work in the background to provide the basic functionality of the program? For example, Photo Booth does certain things when the user interacts with the UI (i.e. changes to video camera when user click on a certain button). However, Photo Booth is also continuously retrieving frames from the camera to provide a video stream.

So my question is where do non-UI tasks code go? Main() isn't really a possibility since I need the tasks to run throughout the life of the program rather than when the program just starts.

I'm on Mac OS X Snow Leopard (I want something that works on all Mac Systems though: i.e. Lion OS X) and am using a Obj-C Cocoa application in Xcode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any application cocoa based Application has access to using [RunLoops](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW1).

Any work your app would want to do, would make use of the RunLoop to execute. Typically this is done on other threads, but if the work is lightweight enough not to cause your UI thread to block, you can run your code on the Main threads RunLoop.

I recommend reading Apple's [Thread Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW1) for more info.

With [Grand Central Dispatch](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091), the programming models have changed to make use of today's multicore systems, so it's possible to define a task and have the OS manage it's execution.

Comment: Thanks, threads sound perfect. I need a centralized place to declare all variables and to start the threads though. Where would I do this?

Comment: In the end, your task is always going to be running in response to something (even if that something is "time passing" or "the app launched"). For something like your Photo Booth example, it will be running in response to callbacks from a video capture library. In the case of a network app, it will be running in response to incoming packets on the network. "Event driven" does not just apply to GUI events.

Comment: If I want it to be "driven" by the app launching, would I put it in main like you would do in console applications?

Comment: @Farhad: No. `main` is almost always a one-liner, doing nothing but call `NSApplicationMain`. You'll typically set up things like you're talking about within your application's delegate or, in a document-based app, each document.